# Error with JSX in my React Library when Switching to Preact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, preact

I have a really simple React library that I use with my own state management.  It's just a Higher Order Component:

```js
import React from 'react';
/**
 * 
 * @param {Object} state - Reference to SubState instance 
 * @param {Object} chunk  - object of props you want maps to from state to props
 */
const connect = (state, chunk)=> Comp => props =>{
    const newProps = {};
    for (let key in chunk){
        newProps[key] = state.getProp(chunk[key]);
    }
    return (<Comp {...newProps} {...props} />)
};

export {
    connect
}
```

I can publish the library this way and I will get a syntax error about being unable to parse `<` in the JSX.

So I run the code through babel

```
//.babelrc

{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

using this webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: 'index.js',     
        library: 'substateConnect',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ["babel-loader"]
          }
        ]
      },
}
```

this is the dependency and publish section of my `package.json`

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "index.map",
    "src/index.js"  
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "substate": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

I'm using `preact-compat` per the website and still getting `<undefined></undefined>`
https://github.com/developit/preact-compat#usage-with-webpack

Currently, running this through babel outputs react in the library and my library and Preact labels any HOC that use this library as `<undefined></undefined>`

IF I publish the un-babel'd code and it is simply the source cope at the top written in new ECMAScript, I get an `unable to parse` error on the `<` in the JSX.

However, if I were to reference the library NOT through `node_modules` but in a developer made files like `myLibrary.js` and use the un-babel'd code, it works.

How do I manage my dependencies correctly?  Should React be a peerDependecy?
Furthermore, how to get this library to work from the `node_modules` directory for BOTH React AND Preact?

Comment: If you're trying to use a React component in Preact, you might need to be using preact-compat

Comment: I'm using that.  I'll update the post.

Comment: Your file is .js right (not .jsx)? Also you're using lots of deprecated libraries, I recommend getting rid of babel-core and babel-preset-* and replacing with @babel/. you have duplicates of babel-core and babel-preset-* there

Comment: @Dominic Awesome.  I will give this a whirl

Comment: @Tamb when you get rid of them best to delete package-lock and node_modules and do a fresh install. Might well not make a difference but good to tick one thing off, also if you are using .jsx you need to edit the webpack config

Comment: @Dominic Good call on clearing the npm cache.  I'm using .js files.

Comment: @Dominic repost my answer below and I'll give you the 50 bounty points

Comment: @Tamb appreciated but np, just accept your one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dominic for helping me clean up my dependencies.

So basically the new dependencies look like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "substate": "^4.0.0",
  }
```

Important to note:  I didn't need React as a dependency.  Any use of webpack and babel are strictly for dev purposes and testing.

The actual final product switched from being a compiled `index.js` file to simply this:

```
import React from 'react';
/**
 * 
 * @param {Object} state - Reference to SubState instance 
 * @param {Object} chunk  - object of props you want maps to from state to props
 */
const connect = (state, chunk)=> Comp => props =>{
    const newProps = {};
    for (let key in chunk){
        newProps[key] = state.getProp(chunk[key]);
    }
    return (<Comp {...newProps} {...props} />)
};

export {
    connect
}
```

The assumption (and I think a safe and fair one) is that anyone using this will compile as needed and `alias` preact into their existing react project.

This assumption allowed me to remove any minification, webpack, or any real compilation from the actual library.  In essence, just use this file as a normal Higher Order Component, React will do the rest with a bundler and swapping React for Preact according to the docs will work as needed.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have `resolve` in your `webpack` file.

Could you please try with the `resolve` config.

```js
{
    // ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react': 'preact-compat',
            'react-dom': 'preact-compat',
            // Not necessary unless you consume a module using `createClass`
            'create-react-class': 'preact-compat/lib/create-react-class',
            // Not necessary unless you consume a module requiring `react-dom-factories`
            'react-dom-factories': 'preact-compat/lib/react-dom-factories'
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The issue was running the library through a compiler.  The library should have been written as a just a Higher Order Component and published as that.  But, your notes about the bottom two preact-compat files are spot on and very important.  I have to test this with React Slick or some other insanely dense React library.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I am glad, it helped you.